# Prototype "classes" vs Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I currently work with prototype, so for instance if i want to create a class or something i would do something like (using it with asp.net)

```
function MyTestClass()
{

this.MyHtmlDiv = $("myHtmlDiv");
this.MyButton = $("myButton");
this.init();
}

MyTestClass.prototype.init = function()
{
  Event.Observe(...some code here ..);
  Event.Observe(...more code...);
}
```

So you get the idea. I like the way it is organized but I have read here in other posts that jquery is better. I would like to start using it but.. is it possible to create "classes" like this, neat?. I usually have a separate .js file for each aspx page. How can I create a class like this with JQuery?

Any pointers, links, ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. When I google this, I see some jquery functions but havent really found a nice template that i can follow to maintain it like above if i was to move to jquery.

Comment: Take a look at http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has no confliction with the style you use now, you just need to change your mind of how jQuery selector work and how to bind event handler etc.

```
function MyTestClass() {
  // note jQuery's selector is different from Prototype    
  this.MyHtmlDiv = $("#myHtmlDiv");
  this.MyButton = $("#myButton");
  this.init();
}

MyTestClass.prototype.init = function() {
  this.MyHtmlDiv.on('event_type', function() {
    // some code
  });
  this.MyButton.on('event_type', function() {
    // some code
  });
}
```